# WCF - Retrieve Types from server in client

Tags: c#, wcf, known-types, serviceknowntype

How to retrieve unknown types of contract in client when the the WCF server implements ServiceKnownType?

Types that pose problems, are not returned or used as a parameter.
I integrated GetKnowTypes() on my server like this: [WCF Problem Sending Object To Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731189/wcf-problem-sending-object-to-client)

```
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesProvider))]
public interface ITestCallback
{
    //What I liked to do:
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TestPropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, Type propertyType, T propertyValue);

    //What I think is required:
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TestSerializedPropertyChanged(string propertyName, string propertyType, string serializedPropertyValue);
}
```

Apparently we can not use Type T. So I serialized my property, and I would like to deserialize in my client, but for that I need the original Type.

I would like to get Types with something like this in the client:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get custom types from server
/// </summary>    
private Type GetPropertyType(string typeName)
{
    try
    {
        var types = KnownTypesProvider.GetKnownTypes(); //ERROR : The name 'KnownTypesProvider' does not exist in current context
        foreach (var knownType in types)
        {
            if (knownType != null && knownType.FullName == typeName)
                return knownType;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Is it possible ? and How ?